# ¿Cómo probar la conexión a un webservice WSDL usando PHP?

Tags: php, html, xml, soap

Buen día, quisiera saber cómo puedo lograr establecer una conexión desde PHP para verificar si el webservice WSDL esta funcionando, actualmente tengo el siguiente código:

```
    <?php
  // Llamada al WebService
  $client = new SoapClient("https://xxxx.xxxx.com:8080/xxxx/xxxx.asmx?WSDL");
  $result = $client->GetCountries();
  $xml = $result->GetCountriesResult;

  // procesar xml
  $xml = simplexml_load_string($xml);
  foreach($xml->Table as $table) 
  {
    $output .= "<p>$table->Name</p>";
  }
  print_r($output);
?>
```

Pero al probar en el navegador me muestra el siguiente error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from.

He agregado la dirección IP desde donde se va a consumir a la lista blanca y aun sigo sin poder establecer conexión, habilité el `SOAP CLIENTE` en el `WHM` y tampoco, y por último lo habilité en el `PHP.ini` y sigo teniendo el mismo problema.

Comment: ¿El mensaje de error completo incluye `failed to load external entity`?

Comment: Si puedes agrega la estructura de tu WSDL, parece que tiene problemas para parsearlo

Comment: Es para una entidad financiera, por eso no puedo compartirlo completo, pero adónde radica el error